# Ternary operator not evaluating checkbox values

Tags: forms

I am using Drupal 7. I have created a form using the Form API, in which I defined several checkboxes. The form sends its contents in an email and this works fine at the moment as long as I simply output the values of the fields, with the checkboxes outputting the value if checked (e.g. Elderly) and 0 if not. In making up the body of the email I want the zeros to be omitted and only the values of the checked boxes to appear. I have tried to achieve this by using a shorthand ternary operator to include some html if the box is checked and not if not. I can't get this to work. Here's how I've defined the checkboxes in the form itself:

```
$hometypes = array(
            'Elderly' => t('Elderly'),
            'Disabled' => t('Disabled'),
            'Council tenant' => t('Council tenant'),
            'Home owner' => t('Home owner')
            );

        $form['personaldetails']['survey']=array(
            '#type'=>'checkboxes',
            '#title'=>t('Please indicate your situation by ticking the appropriate boxes'),
            '#description'=>t('You can tick a box by clicking on it once'),
            '#options'=>$hometypes
            );
```

Here's where I set up the variable $elderly:

```
$elderly = $form_state['values']['survey']['Elderly'];
```

And here's the section of the submit function that is not working:

```
  .($elderly == 'Elderly' ? '<td>Elderly</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td>' : '<td>').
```

This returns the 'True' value regardless of whether the box is checked or not. If I change it to be:

```
  .($elderly <> 0 ? '<td>Elderly</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td>' : '<td>').
```

it returns the 'False' value regardless of whether the box is checked or not.

This may be a bit of a newbie question, but that's because I'm a bit of a newbie! Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I redefined the keys for my checkboxes as values rather than strings. Like so:

```
$hometypes = array(
        1 => t('Elderly'),
        2 => t('Disabled'),
        3 => t('Council tenant'),
        4 => t('Home owner')
        );
```

remembering to change this:

```
$elderly = $form_state['values']['survey'][1];
```

which means that this:

```
($elderly == 1 ? '<td>Elderly</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td>' : '<td>')
```

works perfectly.